# getText() coming up as Null

Tags: java, swing, oop

I am trying to access the text inside of a JTextField. My JTextField is defined in my TextFields class, and the panel I am trying to add the textfield too is defined in my Panels class. My problem is I can not access text entered inside of the text field. I keep getting null even after I have tried to set the text to "TEST"

Should I be doing panel.add in the my TextField class or my Panels class?
Any ideas on what I need to do?

Panels Class:

```
package nameSorting;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panels extends JComponent {
    private JPanel north = new JPanel();
    private JPanel south = new JPanel();
    TextFields fields = new TextFields();
    Buttons buttons = new Buttons();
    ManipData addName = new ManipData();

    public JPanel north(){
        fields.firstNameField(north);

        JButton save = buttons.addSaveName();
        north.add(save);

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println(fields.getFirstName());
            }
        });
        return north;
    }
    public JPanel south(){
        return south;
    }
}
```

TextFields class:

```
package nameSorting;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextFields {

    private JTextField inputFirstName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField inputLastName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField outPutFirstName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField outPutLastName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField showName = new JTextField();
    private String getFirstName;
    private String getLastName;

    public TextFields(){
        // here just in case I need it
    }
    public JTextField firstNameField(JPanel panel){
        inputFirstName.setColumns(10);
        inputFirstName.setText("TEST");
        panel.add(inputFirstName);
        return inputFirstName;
    }
    public void lastNameField(){
        //north.add(inputLastName);
    }
    public void clearFields(){
        inputFirstName.setText(null);
        inputLastName.setText(null);
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        inputFirstName.getText();
        return getFirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        inputLastName.getText();
        return getLastName;
    }
    public JTextField showNames(){
        return showName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the string getfirstname is never assigned to a value..?!

Comment: If you want to keep it like this you probably should use getfirstname = inputFirstName.getText();

Comment: Just saying, maybe you should use another naming convention, get implies usually a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String getFirstName(){
    inputFirstName.getText();
    return getFirstName;
}
```

This should be

```
public String getFirstName(){
    return inputFirstName.getText();
}
```

and get rid of the `getFirstName` field, which is also very poorly named.

Comment: this fixed it. Don't know why I missed that. I also changed the get in the names to text as someone suggested it usually implies a function. thanks.